# Using sklearn with multiple one hot encoded columns

Tags: arrays, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I've been trying to figure out a problem with multiple one hot encoded nparrays.

I'm using a dataframe where every character is a onehot encoding represented in a np_array.

For one example, X features should contain all encodings of the characters, with y being a single label.

My sklearn fit function works when I only take the OHE encoding of the first character of every sample, converted to a list instead of a nparray. This is an example of the code I used to accomplish this:

```
X = df[['char_0']]
X_testing = X.values
empty_list = list()
for entry in X_testing:
    empty_list.append(entry[0].tolist())
```

Now this returns a single list of OHE np arrays of the char_0 for all examples:

```
[ [example0_char0] , [example1_char0] , ... , [examplen_char0] ]
```

---

This is what the X should look like:

```
index, char_0, char_1, ... , char_n
0, [encoding_char0], [encoding_char1], ... , [encoding_charn]
1, [encoding_char0], [encoding_char1], ... , [encoding_charn]
etc.
```

Where each encoding_char, holds a numpy array of a length 38 OHE.

This is what the y should look like:

```
index, label
0, 1
1, 1
etc.
```

My y is okay, but this is what my X looks like:

```
array([[ array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
    array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
    ...,
```

I'm very confused and don't know what to do:

- Should I convert every feature encoding to a list (or should they stay as a np array)?
- Can I train my algorithm on multiple encodings at once? Or is it only possible to fit on a single OHE, not all chars at the same time?

I'd say that you can give Feature1, Feature2, Feature3, where each feature is an entire OHE array.
However, every time I try it I get an error similar to:

- ValueError: Setting an array element with a sequence.
- ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own question after all. I fixed it by doing the following.

```
X = df.loc[:, 'char_0':'char_n']

X = X.values

X = np.array(X)
print(X.shape)

It turned out it was an array of dimensions:
(nsamples * ncolumns * OHElength)

nsamples, nx, ny = X.shape
X = X.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
```

So this simply returns a df with dimensions (nsamples * list of ncols multiplied by the number of characters in one hot encoding).

Sklearn (and Tensorflow) apparently know how to deal with this.